# Kotlin: Cannot apply two conditionals at once check with "return body" function style

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-null-safety

I have a simply function check like this:

```
    fun parseValidBluetoothBrickedId(controllerId: String?): Boolean{
    if(controllerId != null){
        if(controllerId.startsWith(BLUETOOTH_NAME_PREFIX) && controllerId.length > BLUETOOTH_NAME_PREFIX.length)
            return true
    }

    return false
}
```

I want to convert it to simplier style:

```
   fun parseValidBluetoothBrickedId(controllerId: String?) =
        controllerId?.length > BLUETOOTH_NAME_PREFIX.length
      &&  controllerId?.startsWith(BLUETOOTH_NAME_PREFIX)
```

but IDE(Android Studio 3.0 Beta7) gives me an error, underlines the greater than('>') operator:

> Operator calls corresponds to a dot-qualified call 'controllerId?.length.compareTo(BLUETOOTH_NAME_PREFIX.length) which is not allowed here

Also it underline as an error line controllerId?.startsWith(BLUETOOTH_NAME_PREFIX) and says:

> Type mismatch. Required: Boolean, Found Boolean?

What is the problem, really? It is just a simply method, works well with the first block if-else style.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't call `compareTo` (use the `<` operator) on `controllerId?.length`, since its type is `Int?`, which means it might be `null`, in which case it can't be compared as a number.

Similarly, the `controllerId?.startsWith(BLUETOOTH_NAME_PREFIX)` call returns `Boolean?` (since it will return `null` if `controllerId` is `null`), which can't be passed to the the `&&` operator, only a real `Boolean` can.

The solution here is to do the `null` check that you were doing in your original method, and get rid of the safe calls by relying on smart casts casting your `controllerId` to `String`:

```
fun parseValidBluetoothBrickedId(controllerId: String?): Boolean =
        controllerId != null 
        &&  controllerId.length > BLUETOOTH_NAME_PREFIX.length
        &&  controllerId.startsWith(BLUETOOTH_NAME_PREFIX)
```

Answer (score 2):

When you do `controllerId?.length`, you are getting an `Int?`. You cannot compare `Int` with an `Int?`. That is the reason you get the first error.

You get the other error because `controllerId?.startsWith(BLUETOOTH_NAME_PREFIX)` returns `Boolean?`. You cannot use the `&&` operator on a nullable parameter. It requires two parameters of type `Boolean`.

To solve the problems, you need to check `controllerId != null` first. This will smart cast `controllerId` to the non-nullable type `String`. Like this:

```
fun parseValidBluetoothBrickedId(controllerId: String?): Boolean =
    controllerId != null
        && controllerId.startsWith(BLUETOOTH_NAME_PREFIX)
        && controllerId.length > BLUETOOTH_NAME_PREFIX.length
```

Answer (score 1):

Your transformed function is missing the `null` check:

```
fun parseValidBluetoothBrickedId(controllerId: String?) =
        controllerId != null && controllerId.length > "".length
                && controllerId.startsWith("")
```

As in your first example, the null check is necessary for the compiler to know, that `controllerId`  is not `null`. After the check, the compiler uses "smart casting" and the calls are safe.
Therefore you do not have to use `?.` notation after the check.

Comment: I thought the question mark operator is enough for that

Comment: Yes normally it is. But `>` is compiled to `.compareTo()`, without the safe question mark operator, which the compiler does not like here ;-)